# Kubernetes - Implementing Kubernetes Master HA solution in CentOS7

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, kubectl

I am in the process of implementing an HA solution for Kubernetes Master nodes in a CentOS7 env.

My env looks like :

```
K8S_Master1 : 172.16.16.5
K8S_Master2 : 172.16.16.51
HAProxy     : 172.16.16.100
K8S_Minion1 : 172.16.16.50


etcd Version: 3.1.7
Kubernetes v1.5.2
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

My etcd cluster is setup properly and is in working state.

```
[root@master1 ~]# etcdctl cluster-health
member 282a4a2998aa4eb0 is healthy: got healthy result from http://172.16.16.51:2379
member dd3979c28abe306f is healthy: got healthy result from http://172.16.16.5:2379
member df7b762ad1c40191 is healthy: got healthy result from http://172.16.16.50:2379
```

My K8S config for Master1 is :

```
[root@master1 ~]# cat /etc/kubernetes/apiserver 
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001"
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.100.0.0/16"
KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission_control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ResourceQuota"

[root@master1 ~]# cat /etc/kubernetes/config 
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow_privileged=false"
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://127.0.0.1:8080"

[root@master1 ~]# cat /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager 
KUBE_CONTROLLER_MANAGER_ARGS="--leader-elect"

[root@master1 ~]# cat /etc/kubernetes/scheduler 
KUBE_SCHEDULER_ARGS="--leader-elect"
```

As for Master2 , I have configured it to be :

```
[root@master2 kubernetes]# cat apiserver 
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001"
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.100.0.0/16"
KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission_control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ResourceQuota"

[root@master2 kubernetes]# cat config 
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow_privileged=false"
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://127.0.0.1:8080"

[root@master2 kubernetes]# cat scheduler 
KUBE_SCHEDULER_ARGS=""

[root@master2 kubernetes]# cat controller-manager 
KUBE_CONTROLLER_MANAGER_ARGS=""
```

Note that `--leader-elect` is only configured on Master1 as I want Master1 to be the leader.

My HA Proxy config is simple :

```
frontend K8S-Master
    bind 172.16.16.100:8080
    default_backend K8S-Master-Nodes

backend K8S-Master-Nodes
    mode        http
    balance     roundrobin
    server      master1 172.16.16.5:8080 check
    server      master2 172.16.16.51:8080 check
```

Now I have directed my minion to connect to the Load Balancer IP rather than directly to the Master IP.

Config on Minion is :

```
[root@minion kubernetes]# cat /etc/kubernetes/config 
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow_privileged=false"
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://172.16.16.100:8080"
```

On both Master nodes, I see the minion/node status as `Ready`

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS    AGE
172.16.16.50   Ready     2h

[root@master2 ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS    AGE
172.16.16.50   Ready     2h
```

I setup an example nginx pod using :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I created the Replication Controller on `Master1` using :

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl create -f nginx.yaml
```

And on both Master nodes, I was able to see the pods created.

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get po
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-jwpxd   1/1       Running   0          29m
nginx-q613j   1/1       Running   0          29m

[root@master2 ~]# kubectl get po
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-jwpxd   1/1       Running   0          29m
nginx-q613j   1/1       Running   0          29m
```

Now logically thinking, if I were to take down `Master1` node and delete the pods on `Master2` , `Master2` should recreate the pods. So this is what I do.

On `Master1` :

```
[root@master1 ~]# systemctl stop kube-scheduler ; systemctl stop kube-apiserver ; systemctl stop kube-controller-manager
```

On `Master2` :

```
[root@slave1 kubernetes]# kubectl delete po --all
pod "nginx-l7mvc" deleted
pod "nginx-r3m58" deleted
```

Now `Master2` should create the pods since the Replication Controller is still up. But the new Pods are stuck in :

```
[root@master2 kubernetes]# kubectl get po
NAME          READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-l7mvc   1/1       Terminating   0          13m
nginx-qv6z9   0/1       Pending       0          13m
nginx-r3m58   1/1       Terminating   0          13m
nginx-rplcz   0/1       Pending       0          13m
```

Ive waited a long time but the pods are stuck in this state.

But when I restart the services on `Master1` :

```
[root@master1 ~]# systemctl start kube-scheduler ; systemctl start kube-apiserver ; systemctl start kube-controller-manager
```

Then I see progress on `Master1` :

```
NAME          READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-qv6z9   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          14m
nginx-rplcz   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          14m

[root@slave1 kubernetes]# kubectl get po
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-qv6z9   1/1       Running   0          15m
nginx-rplcz   1/1       Running   0          15m
```

Why doesnt `Master2` recreate the pods ? This is the confusion that I am trying to figure out. Ive come a long way to setup a fully function HA setup but seems like almost there only if I can figure out this puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the error comes from the fact that Master2 has no `--leader-elect` flag enabled. There can only be one `scheduler` and `controller` processes running at the same time, that is the reason of `--leader-elect`. The aim of this flag is to have them "compete" to see which of the `scheduler` and `controller` processes is active at a given time. As you did not set the flag in both master nodes, then there are two `scheduler` and `controller` processes active, and thus the conflicts you are experiencing. In order to fix the issue, I advise you to enable this flag in all of the master nodes.

What is more, according to the k8s documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/#best-practices-for-replicating-masters-for-ha-clusters:

> Do not use a cluster with two master replicas. Consensus on a two replica cluster requires both replicas running when changing persistent state. As a result, both replicas are needed and a failure of any replica turns cluster into majority failure state. A two-replica cluster is thus inferior, in terms of HA, to a single replica cluster.